Node20x runtime lambda throws an incorrectly formatted error in AWS Step Functions while Node18x throws an expected error format
AWS lambda running on Node18x runtime throws a different exception when running on Node20x runtime.
I have a lambda function used in AWS state machine. The state machine has a retry mechanism for different exceptions thrown by the lambda. This works when I use Node18x runtime for the lambda. However, it doesn't work on Node20x runtime due to the exception format that bubbles up.
The goal is to move all the lambdas to the latest supported AWS Node runtime
Here's a sample of the step functions lambda:
"Send Request Upstream": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
     "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
     "Parameters": {
          "Payload.$": "$",
           "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:af-south-1:xxxxx:function:do-some-work"
          },
          "Retry": [{
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                         "Lambda.ServiceException",
                         "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                         "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                         "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException",
                         "InternalServerException",
                         "RateLimitException",
                         "TimeoutException"
                     ],
                       "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                       "MaxAttempts": 10,
                       "BackoffRate": 2,
                       "JitterStrategy": "FULL"
                      },
                      {
                        "ErrorEquals": [
                             "UnreachableServerException",
                             "ServiceTemporarilyUnavailableException"
                          ],
                            "IntervalSeconds": 5,
                            "MaxAttempts": 10,
                            "BackoffRate": 3,
                            "JitterStrategy": "FULL"
                           }
                       ],
                       "Next": "DeleteMessage"
              }

Error Thrown by Node18x runtime
{
  "errorType": "UnreachableServerException",
  "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XXX.XX.41:443",
  "trace": [
    "Error: ",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/XXXXXXXXXX/Exception.ts:43:40)",
    "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)",
    "    at Module.m._compile (/XXXXXXXXXX/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/vendor/ts-node@7.0.1/index.js:3009:23)",
    "    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)",
    "    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/XXXXXXXXXX/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/vendor/ts-node@7.0.1/index.js:3011:12)",
    "    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)",
    "    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)",
    "    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/XXXXXXXXXX/utils.ts:4:21)",
    "    at Axios.request (/var/task/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:4224:41)",
    "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
    "    at async __f13.<anonymous> (/var/task/__index.js:464:26)",
    "    at async __f13.<anonymous> (/var/task/__index.js:498:27)",
    "    at async __f9.<anonymous> (/var/task/__index.js:582:26)",
    "    at async Runtime.<anonymous> (/var/task/__index.js:655:22)"
  ]
}

Error Thrown by Node20x runtime
{
  "errorType": "object",
  "errorMessage": "UnreachableServerException",
  "trace": []
}

How the error is thrown
Followed the example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-handling-error-conditions.html
function UnreachableServerException(name, message) {
    this.name = name
    this.message = message
}

UnreachableServerException.prototype = new Error()


throw new UnreachableServerException("UnreachableServerException", message)

I have tried the below, but this never worked even with Node18
class UnreachableServerException extends Error { 
    constructor(name, message) {
        super(message)
        this.name = name
    }
}

throw new UnreachableServerException('UnreachableServerException', 'Unable to reach server")


do you mind adding your entire Lambda code?

Do you mind adding your entire Lambda code? I tested with the following:
export const handler = async (event) => {
   UnreachableServerException.prototype = new Error()
   throw new UnreachableServerException("UnreachableServerException", "my-test")
};

function UnreachableServerException(name, message) {
    this.name = name
    this.message = message
}

and I see:
{
  "errorType": "UnreachableServerException",
  "errorMessage": "my-test",
  "trace": [
    "Error",
    "    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:2:43)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1173:29)"
  ]
}

